# ) was unexpected at this time. Batch error

Tags: batch-file, cmd

```
IF "~1" == "" (
    pause
    set /p training_folder="Enter training folder: "
) else (
    pause
    set training_folder="%~1" & ::business rules file is assumed to be in here
)
pause
```

> ```
> ) was unexpected at this time. Batch error
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magoo gave you the traditional answer - Use `REM` instead of `::` when in parentheses.

But there is another option. You can use undefined variable "expansion" anywhere within your code, even in the middle of a line. The "comment" simply expands to an empty string.

```
set training_folder="%~1" %= business rules file is assumed to be in here =%
```

An `=` cannot appear in variable names, except for the undocumented dynamic pseudo variables like `%=ExitCode%` and `%=ExitCodeAscii%`. An `=` can never appear anywhere other than the first character in the name. I use a pair at the beginning and end for the pleasing visual symmetry, and it is guaranteed to never match the name of a variable, no matter the content.

The only restriction is your "comment" cannot contain `:` or `%`.

Answer (score 2):

Replace the `::` with `rem`. As it is, there appears to be a label within a code-block, which is not usually allowed.